# How to delete a user's authentication information from a website hosted on firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I made a website application using React and Redux that takes in the user's email and password to log in. The website is hosted on firebase so user is stored in the database. Look at photo below:

[image]

A few days ago, I deleted one of the user's collections. After deleting it, I went back into my website and signed in with the same email and password and it worked. I have been trying to figure out why this is happening.

Please ask me questions if anything I said is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user account information is not stored in firestore, although it is a common practice to create user documents.

If you go into the 'Authentication' area in Firestore you'll see user accounts and can delete them manually.

Or you can call the delete method in your app (delete the user, not the document).

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Comment: Wow... For some reason, I didn't think to check that. Thank you very much!